# File Similarity Checker using Python 2.7.15

Tags: python-2.7, file, file-io, similarity

I'm attempting to make a python script that outputs the similarities of 2 different files onto a third file. I understand there is a simple way to do this by checking through each line on both of the files using nested for loops, but I chose not to do this because I'm trying to make it run as fast as possible. This is because I'm working with semi-large files (100-200MB each) and checking each line on both files would take much longer than what I stumbled across next:

A quick alternative I found was importing mmap and using the .find() function to check each line in the first file

```
import mmap
import time
RESULTS = open('sims.txt', 'w')
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f = open('file2.txt')
f2 = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
for line1 in f1:
    if len(line1) > 3:
        if f2.find(line1) != -1:
            RESULTS.write(line1)
RESULTS.close()
f1.close()
```

This method is very quick at reading the second file, and has no syntax errors, yet it just doesn't function properly. Here is an example of file1.txt and file2.txt

file1:

```
orange

hotdog
pig
```

file2:

```
apple
mango
orange
pig

hotdog
```

The output should be orange and hotdog on sims.txt, but sims.txt is always blank. Please let me know if there's a way to fix this, or a better way to do this while still maintaining the speed of the find() function, or if it's just not possible. Thanks!

(P.S. I just started learning python 2-3 days ago so it's very possible that I made a simple mistake)

Answer (score 0):

You can test with `if line1 in f:`

```
import time
RESULTS = open('sims.txt', 'w')
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f = open('file2.txt')
for line1 in f1:
    if len(line1) > 3:
        if line1 in f:
            RESULTS.write(line1)
RESULTS.close()
f1.close()
```

You have to be careful because line1 is reading newlines

Comment: This worked for the small example I gave with file1 and file2, but it seems to not work on a large scale. I'm working with process memory dumps using Process Hacker (A tool that extracts strings from the memory of currently running processes). Each dump is around 10 million strings (each string is on a separate line). When I run it, it takes about 5 seconds and doesn't output anything to sims.txt. It also doesnt provide me with any errors.